# Which Java Spring components needed for Spring-WS?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I have Eclipse Kepler installed and working properly on Mac OSX.  I'd like to install Spring in order to design, write, deploy a  RESTful web service.

I see a plethora of components listed on the update site, and little guidance on what I do/don't need in order to just get started.

Do I need :

SpringSource DM Server Tools?
Spring IDE Core Developer Resources?
Web Flow?

Comment: A note on the question above. Spring-WS is for contract-first SOAP services. If you're looking to write REST services, then you should be looking at Spring-MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Eclipse installed then just follow the tutorial: Building a RESTful Web Service

http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

It provides details of the Maven/Gradle configuration that you need which will ensure that the correct dependencies are imported.

Note that it makes use of Spring Boot, which in turn will import dependencies required by Spring MVC. You don't need Spring-WS for REST web services. Spring-WS is for building SOAP web services.

Comment: Thanks for the tip re: Spring-WS